# Weird unexpected token error when trying to name a class

Tags: javascript, class, token

I am trying to name a class in Javascript and when I initialize the class it has an error at the name of the class.

```
class e {.  //SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:6)
  constructor(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
  }
}
```

Also, if I make another, identical in everything but name, class under it then there is no error on the second class.

```js
class e { //SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:6)
  constructor(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
  }
}

class a { //all that comes up here is that a is not called in my program
  constructor(and, what) {
    this.and = and;
    this.what = what;
  }
}
```

When I add a third class nothing happens to the second class, no errors are coming up. So I have no idea why this is happening.

This is for a school project and we are using Code.org's App Lab if that makes a difference.

I copied a class from another program that works and pasted it into this program and changed only the names, hoping that error would go away, but the error still is there.

Comment: is `.` in `class e {.` in the first code a typo

Comment: I added a snippet to show that there is no syntax error

Comment: at a guess, you have some, possibly invisible, invalid character in your code - try re-typing the offending line (and the line before and after) - I gather `(13:6)` identifies the line `class e {`

Comment: Yes, (13:6) identifies 'class e {' and yes, I tried deleting everything but it still comes up with the error. Here are some screenshots of the error. https://ibb.co/DQy74m6 https://ibb.co/12LTx7B

Comment: Your screenshots are missing the first 8 lines.

Comment: here is a screenshot with the top lines, I didn't think they were important https://ibb.co/dLwf3PM

Comment: I created a new program and tried to make a class but the same error came up. Here is a picture of that program. https://ibb.co/0tBbFyy

Comment: What code editor are you using? It might not support class syntax.

Comment: I found documentation saying that the website that I use for school doesn’t support classes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Code.org does not support `class`. Here is a forum post about it.https://forum.code.org/t/oop-and-class-impementation-tech-help/31755/3
It explains that `class` is not implemented into the interpreter that is used, however it gives a clever solution to create a `class` using functions. It appears to work the same way a `class` would, just without `class` syntax.

Comment: *"it gives a clever solution to create a class using functions"* That's not a clever solution, that's the old solution.

Comment: If the platform does not support even ES2015, I think it's time to find another platform that's more up-to-date. Don't dumb your code down for the sake of horribly ancient environments - use a more modern environment instead.